# Doubts about the use of a key retrieved from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

I created a key vault and granted access to my application. The permissions I provided were: Get, Decrypt, Encrypt, Verify, Sign. My goal is to retrieve a key stored in the Key Vault and sign a POST request before sending it to the target API. The default format of a private key is:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAqBkqnCFfp6jnQHO4inLGGIWaOQks1uJVP0AVbznN5313Mmoj 37vLDbheGE7Wi988G6O3zGD4xDroYIK36O7WaTgrCQpd9PYSRACrOvpr9gWXc7Ug bouz7WMoEPJ3jHbleowo2Gnf3JSGUfj/wKm3BRAo3fq79hiurfdjg/W1R9P21kdS d8xkfuA7aqNIRlWD+ub6hJ/11Fxk+PJ8WVTvLW1tk+Kz0TmqMN18bzIrkxr1S1gl B/6IzbKnz55rLWEIbopBv4152gEI+xYlrVPbZFfbAM/Hl/ksRz2YNRvIfAunkuAm vDbrh4k702V5K4SOc6SzQn0/9YUt+tfdQ9KIhQIDAQABAoIBAAQayTa3WMN13l+2 hfUQEh2tdXybDQj1qLs68IHoNNzsx6kw6k2fbJR1eOa56GKs0+8zIRPQzctoSovA wM++/mXixPEbSSCfAr4G695RGNAQ0Afuab3AJme9PqvI+1UwJ8LqAvQsus06EhNL fPD3IagW2cidQ5yPn3IInCLmwnopD0quyqE9hGSn/CaMTLZYGaEqQqSisR/LrTB3 9qJ40pFHfbp6Lc6RRCRAJbnMfDTFviGtQfl8kxydLiZtmbQdWrJF33blcqP3GtPf 9nVF5Nu5zqmH2wfwb0oMVusrPgV1I1Edf9NWvN3T+xCmhAm529AvwxncRtgGfoec 7BL2rWkCgYEA0rgd0VbadGC6M0HkorUd8TUeovtGKB7GD2lMqPxTn+dH9Z+bVDuu 6fl8mhadguETklrRC90lBTnluC2zBtZcFg47M5kdF5HuKkOx00Gl+ctmey2UphCJ vRkSwuInb1kPLheWxH11CdyCNCgFrWJjKgNOADAY/96+l0Qh7Mm5EQcCgYEAzDhu CVPt+XW06tJs3BVE7HlhKw7rR2R3yDbuOwA3lFHWdtzBRZhXWurdqmkL/zLh8he0 RBp9jIdGqpZlUJhBbGE5KIliSgOZ2bb9v/adf1gph+DQdFXt+xnXflUfZVHVFs6p QwfpSwWG9KVodiOw2J3Wp0tZfPeG9+naJJmnUxMCgYEAx8sw4nsieHP6OH2Cxk9K S5kdKlVriMDc9GHYAOX2eEf3r8mconpQd6JJZWSKBj1YrE0VptUQs+rYiBA0jggT mgn2Ug8cSWvhUQuMgQzezYDw81wddHN71eL/Ke76ixX7Ua2mEzoNDcOZZNCJyYLf GUe23nC8U2ckeRJtxDDkG2MCgYBRaVWEZm8B+YiL7CL1gY0ecCzqS2JD7atKp4tE /gsqF43ViJ+LrPV2Cxce7g2YSKKGLijw1VajhPII4ze0b131ZLSykkIam2Djx+1U b23N7ElyH486MV9TsLOVaz2+2GaIVw5m6Gp6O9PXB3GjVwsS76k4u/MKvGqTvif2 W0K2/QKBgQCG1OmGAKmPjtiBHCrfUPo4qPuiw7fYKS7sTrEKBiDdB8cQF6VR5wz4 RWRE/Ng/q8GROhXJ6HbLgsIzbvD4rL4nbG4pQ3LPSpQPsXDN2JOaE9nqUukUBWyo
OMQ8TcTgGRf2eTz0f/rRxGrGEzavLpoe8UszDADWSUsMZEL/Y4EnwA==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

However, when accessing my key vault and trying to retrieve my key for signing the request, this is the return I get:

"key": { "kid": " [https://nerokeys.vault.azure.net/keys/PrivateKeyNero-Qi-Rbm/0e3...e5f"](https://nerokeys.vault.azure.net/keys/PrivateKeyNero-Qi-Rbm/0e3...e5f%22), "kty": "RSA", "key_ops": [ "sign", "verify", "wrapKey", "unwrapKey", "encrypt", "decrypt" ], "n": "uiMiRntQj1VU_4KCL3G-SlY-xoJ2zh10ptvaLWioLR64qgRK693f96t2xWBfAY96JOlOwIC3ztRM3mP7ec_UZixQuX7VjcaPUWkRRKW3Wr7wVIx2CFVtO4RULWj9wpobCD41Kv-tyJ3cCHMEcMVI-BO8-IzoRfK74jPaZjscIM-bqE7ia4Xc6ETuri5Hbn5JrGrQ0aWT5nWWfN02sP1mV-en6aR9gdmcmBOaS8mNY5f1hIvs2PdPqGopHeKYdFA_1KKUm5_eeDIqxvvb5JbPz5nvqW2MFLQreyy-Pr6crvfcNplUAuCd9x_TzRWe5Ip-m-i3RrGmZCDtyIlR_z6RyQ", "e": "AQAB" }, "attributes": { "enabled": true, "created": 1705409666, "updated": 1705409666, "recoveryLevel": "CustomizedRecoverable+Purgeable", "recoverableDays": 30 }, "tags": []

My question is, how do I use this return? Do I use the value of 'n' to sign the request? Although it seems not to be the private key. Or when using the value of a key in the key vault to sign requests, should I send the request to the key vault, and it returns the signed request? If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

We haven't attempted to make the request yet as the question is about how to proceed with the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on Azure Q&A and got an excellent answer to this question:

"that response you got is like peeking through the window but not quite getting the whole view. the public key (n and e), not the private key. The private key is securely stored within the Key Vault,

For signing requests, you don't manually dael 'n' and 'e'; that's Azure Key Vault's job. You ask it to sign your data, and it does its magic with the private key, which you can't directly see

To put it in a nutshell . you hand Azure Key Vault your data, and it hands back the signature. Your app then sends the data and the signature to the target API."

Does anyone have documentation/example code on how to perform this operation?

Send my data to the Key Vault, have it use the private key to sign the data and return the signed hash, which I will use to send to the external API.